# Fetching dependencies from private and public maven/sbt artifacts repos

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, artifactory

I'm configuring setting to get artifacts with maven/sbt from private repos (JFROG artifactory). So, I configured to get all dependencies from it, but what to do when some public dependecy is not in my private repo? (for example download failed: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.5.9!httpclient.jar).

Should I specify two sources, like private and public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the Artifactory, it is usually the best idea to manage all repositories (internal and external) ones in your Artifactory and reference just this Artifactory in your `settings.xml`.

Artifactory allows you to proxy any external Maven repository.